# "back" button function at upper left with '<-' icon on chrome browser error, somehow affect my website

Tags: css, google-chrome, back-button

My original/default frontpage of index.html is already fine and working, sometime I'd clicked at Back-Button of Chrome browser and it goes back to it original/default view but sometime when I'd clicked at Back-Button of Chrome browser, my frontpage move slightly to the left outside of screen view.

This is my original look of frontpage
[image: Original Frontpage]

and this is what happen sometime when i click back button
[image: Frontpage after click on back-button]

So I've tried to create custom button inside my webpage that have same function as Back-Button on Chrome Browser with following js `<script>function goBack() {window.history.back();}</script>` but the result still the same.

There is no changes occur at any CSS or JS when I inspect it, can anybody help me?

Comment: Make a working JSFiddle. It's impossible to know what's wrong without seeing the code

Comment: @EranGoldin Kinda hard to replicate the exact code in simplify way to get the same result without exposing my code. I already double-triple check it and going through back forth between pages but there's no changes at all at related CSS or JS. May be you can suggest convenient tool other than Chrome Developer Tool or Firebug Lite for me?

Comment: No, but I can suggest remove elements from the page until the bug stops reproducing, to reduce what you have to examine.

Comment: @EranGoldin I see, good suggestion, i'll look into it and share if i find the cause

Comment: Problems fixed, sorry i can't provide the answer to my own questions, cause i already forgotten what i did